# How do I uninstall or remove TailsOS from my flash drive?

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, troubleshooting, uninstall

I'm using Windows 10 and have tried formatting it and removing all partitions. When I open the flash drive (FD) I get an error message that says "Please insert a disk into USB Drive (D:)."

I just tried to format the FD using file explorer-> right clicking the FD-> clicking format-> deselecting quick format-> formatting the FD but i got an error message saying that "windows was unable to complete the format."

Comment: When you attempted to format the partition, what error or message, did you receive exactly?

Comment: Because it has a file system?  That isn’t unusual in the slightest.  You should edit your question instead of submitting vital information as a temporary comment

Comment: Really? The entirety of the storage isn't usable? I'm sure I've seen it say it had sixteen gigabytes available before.

Comment: 14.91 GB is the entire amount of storage the device supports with a file system.  This concept isn’t new. It’s the difference between base 10 and base 2.  I won’t respond to any additional commentary about that subject (you haven’t done proper amount of research)

Answer (score 1):

Use **diskmgmt** it should be preinstalled with your windows device .You should see your partitions there.Search for your usb drive and right click on it and press format and choose the file type you want your usb to be based on.(fat32 etc)

> (Note using this will not erase them in a secure fashion)

**Alternative**

> Make sure the USB you want to erase is unplugged. Then launch the
>   Command Prompt with Administrative Rights. (click the start button,
>   type in "cmd" (without quotations), right-click the first option and
>   click on "Run as Administrator.")

At the command-line window, type in this command:

```
diskpart
```

Type in this command to list the current disks connected to the computer:

```
list disk
```

Plug in the USB that you want to erase and type in this command afterward:

```
list disk
```

A new disk should appear in the list. To select it, type in this command:

```
select disk=*number*
```

Replace number with the disk number of your USB.

6. Type in this command:

> clean

Then this command:

```
convert mbr
```

Finally, this command:

```
 create partition primary
```

7. Close the Command Prompt. If Windows tells you to format the USB afterward, do so

**SOURCE**
https://www.reddit.com/r/tails/comments/dc5yu2/how_to_remove_tails_from_usb/